# Setting up Elastic inference accelerator with aws deep learning AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pytorch

I am trying to launch an instance with AWS deep learning AMI with an elastic inference accelerator. I have set the role for the policy for the IAM to connect as described in the documentation "elastic-inference:Connect". But When i try launch the instance i get the error. Initiating launches failure invalid attachment reservation 0 for accelerator type : eia1.medium

I tried adding further permission. I added the following permissions.

- AmazonEC2FullAccess
- AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryFullAccess
- GlobalAcceleratorFullAccess
- trial_policy.json (contains the json which is mentioned in the documentation for adding "elastic-inference:Connect")
- AmazonDevOpsGuruFullAccess

But is still get the following error.

- Launch Failed Invalid attachment reservation 0 for accelerator type :
  eia1.medium.
- Verifying entitlement to product  Successful
- Initiating launches   Failure